# Term Frequencies in Redisearch

Tags: frequency, redisearch

Is there a way in Redisearch to get the frequency of the term searched? For example if I had the following documents in Redisearch

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE myIndex SCHEMA fileName TEXT SORTABLE content TEXT SORTABLE docId TAG SORTABLE NOINDEX
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myIndex doc1 1.0 FIELDS fileName file1 content "lorem ipsum" docId doc1
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myIndex doc2 1.0 FIELDS fileName file2 content "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum" docId doc2
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.ADD myIndex doc3 1.0 FIELDS fileName file3 content "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum" docId doc3
OK
```

Is there a way to get the count of the word "lorem" in each document?

I tried this aggregate command but could not get the frequency of the search term.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.AGGREGATE myIndex "lorem" GROUPBY 1 @content REDUCE COUNT 0 as frequency
1) (integer) 3
2) 1) "content"
   2) "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
   3) "frequency"
   4) "1"
3) 1) "content"
   2) "lorem ipsum"
   3) "frequency"
   4) "1"
4) 1) "content"
   2) "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum"
   3) "frequency"
   4) "1"
```

Comment: https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/issues/171